# Proving that the limit doesn't exist for $x$ other than $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, real-numbers, epsilon-delta

I have a problem/proof that I can't quite solve.

> Let
>
> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\quad &x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus
>  \mathbb{Q}\\-x^2 \quad &x \in \mathbb{Q}.\\ \end{cases}$$
>
> Prove that
>
> $$\lim_{x\to n} f(x)$$
>
> doesn't exist for $n$ other than $0$.

Maybe I can use the regular epsilon-delta proof? I tried that but wasn't sure of what assumptions I could make with the absolute values. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: For every number $n$ there can be found a sequence $r_p$ of rational numbers and a sequence $i_p$ of irational numbers ,(p going from 1 to infinity) that converge to $n$. The limit of $f(r_p)$ will be $-n^2$ and the limit of $f(i_p)$ will be $n^2$ . Since they are distinct values, then the limit for general $x$ can't exist for $f(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using well known definition of limit [In terms of sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function) by Eduard Heine, let's take $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $x_n=\frac{1}{n}+q \in \mathbb{Q} $ and $x_n \to q, n \to \infty.$ So $f(x_n)=-x_n^2 \to -q^2$.

From another hand we know, that between each pair of rational numbers exist irrationals, so we can choose sequence $q< y_n<x_n  $ and $y_n \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. As $y_n \to q$ and $f(y_n)=y_n^2 \to q^2$, then we obtain that for limit does not exist if not holds $q^2=-q^2$. But this is only for $q=0.$

Comment: @Xander Henderson. I am asking here, because do not know other place, sorry if this is not correct. I copy/paste this answer to new question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816374/proving-that-a-limit-of-piecewise-function-defined-for-rationals-and-irrationals/3816442?noredirect=1#comment7874341_3816442 because, when I saw it and try to vote for close as duplicate, then cannot find in reference search box this question. What should I do in future in analogical situation?