# Proving that a limit of piecewise function defined for rationals and irrationals does not exist

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta, irrational-numbers

A function is defined as follows:
$$
 f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      x^2 & x \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q} \\
      -x^2 & x \in \mathbb{Q}
   \end{cases}
$$

Show that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ does not exist for $a \ne 0$.

I'm really stuck on this problem. Is there a way to show this using epsilon-delta definitions or work with series? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try two different sequences converging to the same point; is there a clear choice how to choose the numbers for each?

Comment: Use the fact that between any 2 rationals, however close together, we can always find irrationals, and between any 2 irrationals, however close together, we can always find rationals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a\neq 0$. It suffices to choose two sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=a,$$
but
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)\neq\lim_{n\to\infty}f(b_n).
$$
In your particular case, if $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ you can take $a_n=a+\frac{1}{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $b_n=a+\frac{\pi}{n}\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. If $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ you can always suppose that there exists a sequence $A_k\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $A_k\to a$ (since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$), and choose for instance $a_n=A_n+\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=a+\frac{1}{n}$. In both cases
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=-\lim_{n\to\infty}f(b_n).
$$